# Move camera based on device movements in ARKit with SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, metal

Is it possible to move the camera based on how the user's device moves in the real world, when using ARKit with **SceneKit**?

Elaboration (2018-02-09): Assume I point my device in a direction and see a virtual AR object in front of me. When I move 2 meters to the right (but keep pointing in the same direction), my desire is that I don't see the AR object anymore (because the camera of the scene "equals" me / my device and the object moved out of the viewport of the camera.

Details on how to understand my status:

In the current Xcode version 9.2,

- When I create a project for ARKit > with **Metal**, I get a template app where the camera moves as the device moves (my desired behavior)
- When I create a project for ARKit > with **SceneKit**, I get a template app where the camera doesn't respond to movements of the device

I would like to have an app using SceneKit where the camera moves as it does in the Metal template.

I could imagine that this could be done as easy as setting a property in the scene; or it might have to be done programmatically. But even after a few hours of research, I did not find anything about this.

Update (2018-02-16): I found out what hindered me before and I still don't understand it:
Only if I use or copy the original scene (scn file) contained in the ARKit template project, it behaves as desired (and the scene background in the scene editor is shown white, see screenshot with ball2.scn):
[image]
If I create my own scn file and try to achieve the same, the ARWorldTrackingConfiguration seems to have no effect (and the scene background in the scene editor is shown gray, see screenshot with ball.scn):
[image]
I did not find any property of the scene which could be related to this.

Comment: do you have your configuration as ARWorldTrackingConfiguration?

Also, to clarify your question a bit? Are you wanting an object to always orient itself so it is easily visible to the user? For example, when you walk a few steps to the right and look at the model from a different angle, you want to be able to see the front of it like you did previously?

Comment: Thanks, Jake, for the comment! Actually I want the exact opposite of what you wrote in your comment. ^^ I updated the question with an elaboration. 

Nevertheless, the ARWorldTrackingConfiguration you mentioned seems to exactly provide the features for my desire. I will check it out! Do you know of maybe any additional options/approaches?

Comment: I think if you set that configuration correctly, you would get your desired result. In my experience, it would disappear if I took a few steps to the right(or far enough that the object is out of the camera's visibility) the object would not be visible until you returned close to the original position the object was placed in the ARWorld.

Comment: You are right, Jake, I got it working now that way. However, I found out what hindered me before and I still don't understand it: Only if I use or copy the original scene (scn file) contained in the ARKit template project, it behaves as desired (and the scene background in the scene editor is shown white). If I create my own scn file and try to achieve the same, the ARWorldTrackingConfiguration seems to have no effect (and the scene background in the scene editor is shown gray). I did not find any property which cold be related to this.

Comment: A picture of the difference between the two scenarios would be nice to see. Kind of hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: OK, Jake, I added pictures to the description. (Don't get disturbed by the Xcode graphic error in the scene graph in the first picture, this is not related to the white/gray background.)

Comment: Is the new .scn file showing up when you run the app? Or it is and it's just not behaving correctly?

Comment: When I build the app using the ball2.scn file and run it, I see the orange ball and ARWorldTrackingConfiguration behaves correctly. When I build the app using ball.scn file and run it, I see the ball, but it always stays in front of the camera no matter how far I move (translation) in the real world with my device.